# Swift `Failure` keyword meaning in a Swift Combine chain error

Tags: swift, combine

Let's say that I've this simple chain that from an HTTP request creates a publisher for `<T, APIManagerError>`

```
   func run<T:Decodable>(request:URLRequest)->AnyPublisher<T, APIManagerError>{
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map{$0.data}
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()// it should run mapError before this point
    }
```

This code produces this error since I'm returning Error instead of `APIManagerError`.

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 
'AnyPublisher<T, Publishers.Decode<Upstream, Output, Coder>.Failure>' 
(aka 'AnyPublisher<T, Error>') 
to return type 'AnyPublisher<T, RestManagerError>'
```

I know that to fix the issue I need to add a mapError after `.decode`.

```
.mapError{error in 
    APIManagerError.error("Decode Fail")
}
```

but I can't really understand what is reported with the error message before the "aka" part that is quite clear instead

How do you read the error `Publishers.Decode<Upstream, Output, Coder>.Failure`? specifically what does it mean the `.Failure` part? where can I find the `Failure` in the Swift Doc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since we are talking about two different kinds of errors here lets denote a *C*ompilation *E*rror as `CE` and the `Failure` of a `Publisher` (conforming to `Swift.Error`) as `PF` (*P*ublisher *F*ailure).

Your question is about the interpretation of the `CE` message.

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 
'AnyPublisher<T, Publishers.Decode<Upstream, Output, Coder>.Failure>'
```

Writes out the resulting returned type of your implementation of `func run` - without the `mapError` call. The compiler acknowledges your call to `eraseToAnyPublisher()` in the end of the function, and also your generic `Output` of type `T`. So that covers the `Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<T,`. As to `Publishers.Decode<Upstream, Output, Coder>.Failure>'` outputs the derived type of the `Failure`. This is somewhat a symbolic breakdown of the derived `Failure` type. Your upstream Publisher is initially of type [`URLSession.DataTaskPublisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/datataskpublisher), as a result of your `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher` call, which you then transform with every Combine operator you call: `map` and then `decode`. Resulting in the publisher [`Publishers.Decode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/decode). And the `Failure` type of cannot be properly "desymbolised" (I lack the proper compiler knowledge to use the correct terminology).

Which Xcode version do you use? The [New Diagnostic Architecture](https://swift.org/blog/new-diagnostic-arch-overview/) might be able to show a better error message. This is in fact the reason why I later in my response use `.assertMapError(is: DecodingError.self)`

Your code in `mapError` does the job, but it completely tossed away information about the actual error. So I would not do that. At least print (log) the error. But still I would do something like:

### Declare custom Error type

Intuitively we have at least two different kinds of errors, either `networking` or decoding. But potentially more...

```swift
public enum HTTPError: Swift.Error {
    indirect case networkingError(NetworkingError)
    indirect case decodingError(DecodingError)
}

public extension HTTPError {
    enum NetworkingError: Swift.Error {
        case urlError(URLError)
        case invalidServerResponse(URLResponse)
        case invalidServerStatusCode(Int)
    }
}
```

You might need to tell combine that the error type is indeed `DecodingError`, thus I've declared some `fatalError` macros useful for this information. It is somewhat simular to Combine's `setFailureType` (but which only works when the upstream publisher has `Failure` type `Never`, thus we cannot use it here).

### castOrKill

```swift
func typeErasureExpected<T>(
    instance incorrectTypeOfThisInstance: Any,
    toBe expectedType: T.Type,
    _ file: String = #file,
    _ line: Int = #line
) -> Never {
    let incorrectTypeString = String(describing: Mirror(reflecting: incorrectTypeOfThisInstance).subjectType)
    fatalError(
        "Incorrect implementation: Expected variable '\(incorrectTypeOfThisInstance)' (type: '\(incorrectTypeString)') to be of type `\(expectedType)`",
        file, line
    )
}

func castOrKill<T>(
    instance anyInstance: Any,
    toType: T.Type,
    _ file: String = #file,
    _ line: Int = #line
    ) -> T {
    guard let instance = anyInstance as? T else {
        typeErasureExpected(instance: anyInstance, toBe: T.self, file, line)
    }
    return instance
}
```

And then create a convenience method on `Publisher`, similar to `setFailureType`:

```swift
extension Publisher {
    func assertMapError<NewFailure>(is newFailureType: NewFailure.Type) -> AnyPublisher<Output, NewFailure> where NewFailure: Swift.Error {
        return self.mapError { castOrKill(instance: $0, toType: NewFailure.self) }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

### Usage:

I took the liberty of catching some more errors in your examples. Asserting e.g. that the server responds with a non failure HTTP status code etc.

```swift
func run<Model>(request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<Model, HTTPError> where Model: Decodable {
    URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
        .mapError { HTTPError.NetworkingError.urlError($0) }
        .tryMap { data, response -> Data in
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                throw HTTPError.NetworkingError.invalidServerResponse(response)
            }
            guard case 200...299 = httpResponse.statusCode else {
                throw HTTPError.NetworkingError.invalidServerStatusCode(httpResponse.statusCode)
            }
            return data
    }
    .decode(type: Model.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())

    // It's unfortunate that Combine does not pick up that failure type is `DecodingError`
    // thus we have to manually tell the Publisher this.
    .assertMapError(is: DecodingError.self)
    .mapError { HTTPError.decodingError($0) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

### Bonus - equality check for `HTTPError`

It is indeed very advantageous if our error types are `Equatable`, it makes writing unit tests so much easier. Either we go the `Equatable` route, or we can do some reflection magic. I will present both solutions, but the Equatable solution is more robust for sure.

#### Equatable

In order to make `HTTPError` conform to `Equatable` we only need to manually make `DecodingError` equatable. I've done this with this code:

```swift
extension DecodingError: Equatable {

    public static func == (lhs: DecodingError, rhs: DecodingError) -> Bool {

        switch (lhs, rhs) {

            /// `typeMismatch` is an indication that a value of the given type could not
            /// be decoded because it did not match the type of what was found in the
            /// encoded payload. As associated values, this case contains the attempted
            /// type and context for debugging.
        case (
            .typeMismatch(let lhsType, let lhsContext),
            .typeMismatch(let rhsType, let rhsContext)):
            return lhsType == rhsType && lhsContext == rhsContext

            /// `valueNotFound` is an indication that a non-optional value of the given
            /// type was expected, but a null value was found. As associated values,
            /// this case contains the attempted type and context for debugging.
        case (
            .valueNotFound(let lhsType, let lhsContext),
            .valueNotFound(let rhsType, let rhsContext)):
            return lhsType == rhsType && lhsContext == rhsContext

            /// `keyNotFound` is an indication that a keyed decoding container was asked
            /// for an entry for the given key, but did not contain one. As associated values,
            /// this case contains the attempted key and context for debugging.
        case (
            .keyNotFound(let lhsKey, let lhsContext),
            .keyNotFound(let rhsKey, let rhsContext)):
            return lhsKey.stringValue == rhsKey.stringValue && lhsContext == rhsContext

            /// `dataCorrupted` is an indication that the data is corrupted or otherwise
            /// invalid. As an associated value, this case contains the context for debugging.
        case (
            .dataCorrupted(let lhsContext),
            .dataCorrupted(let rhsContext)):
            return lhsContext == rhsContext

        default: return false
        }
    }
}

extension DecodingError.Context: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: DecodingError.Context, rhs: DecodingError.Context) -> Bool {
        return lhs.debugDescription == rhs.debugDescription
    }
}
```

Which, as you can see, also has to make `DecodingError.Context` Equatable.

Then you can declare these XCTest helpers:

```swift
    func XCTAssertThrowsSpecificError<ReturnValue, ExpectedError>(
        file: StaticString = #file,
        line: UInt = #line,
        _ codeThatThrows: @autoclosure () throws -> ReturnValue,
        _ error: ExpectedError,
        _ message: String = ""
    ) where ExpectedError: Swift.Error & Equatable {

        XCTAssertThrowsError(try codeThatThrows(), message, file: file, line: line) { someError in
            guard let expectedErrorType = someError as? ExpectedError else {
                XCTFail("Expected code to throw error of type: <\(ExpectedError.self)>, but got error: <\(someError)>, of type: <\(type(of: someError))>")
                return
            }
            XCTAssertEqual(expectedErrorType, error, line: line)
        }
    }

    func XCTAssertThrowsSpecificError<ExpectedError>(
        _ codeThatThrows: @autoclosure () throws -> Void,
        _ error: ExpectedError,
        _ message: String = ""
    ) where ExpectedError: Swift.Error & Equatable {
        XCTAssertThrowsError(try codeThatThrows(), message) { someError in
            guard let expectedErrorType = someError as? ExpectedError else {
                XCTFail("Expected code to throw error of type: <\(ExpectedError.self)>, but got error: <\(someError)>, of type: <\(type(of: someError))>")
                return
            }
            XCTAssertEqual(expectedErrorType, error)
        }
    }

    func XCTAssertThrowsSpecificErrorType<Error>(
        _ codeThatThrows: @autoclosure () throws -> Void,
        _ errorType: Error.Type,
        _ message: String = ""
    ) where Error: Swift.Error & Equatable {
        XCTAssertThrowsError(try codeThatThrows(), message) { someError in
            XCTAssertTrue(someError is Error, "Expected code to throw error of type: <\(Error.self)>, but got error: <\(someError)>, of type: <\(type(of: someError))>")
        }
    }
```

#### Reflection magic

Or you can take a look at my [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/Sajjon/3f7dafdd341a42e675f3d830572c50b2) which does not make use of Equatable at all, but can "compare" any enums errors which are not conforming to Equatable.

### Usage

Together with [`CombineExpectation`](https://github.com/groue/CombineExpectations) you can now write unit tests of your Combine code and compare errors more easily!

Comment: Great explanation, but my question wasn't about converting errors... I was just asking the meaning of `Failure` here... I can't accept the reply even if the description is extremely clear. Could you just add a couple of sentences where you explain what the keyword `Failure` does here and add all this description to explain why my mapError example wasn't correct maybe?

Comment: Sure, I will update my answer in a couple of hours when Im at a computer

Comment: @MatterGoal I updated with more info about `Failure`,

Answer (score 0):

I've easily found the answer actually but I keep the question open in case someone else needed it.

The `Failure` keyword in this case is just the `associatedtype` that comes with the `Publisher` protocol.

In this case I'm just  getting the `Failure` type for the  `Publishers.Decode`, that by default is just `Error`.

Comment: and exactly why the -1?